# Ionic build fail : "Could not find firebase-messaging.aar" after adding fcm plugin

Tags: android, cordova, firebase, ionic-framework, cordova-plugin-fcm

The ionic project builds successfully without the 'fcm' plugin, but it fails when its added.
There is no problem regarding running the project, but the build fails.
The error shown is :

> - What went wrong:
>     A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
>     Could not find firebase-messaging.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0).
>     Searched in the following locations:
>       https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/17.0.0/firebase-messaging-17.0.0.aar